# Installation issues with percona

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, percona

When Installing Percona XtraDB Cluster on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - fresh OS install - I get the following errors:

> Unpacking percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.6 (from .../percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.6_5.6.15-25.2-645.precise_amd64.deb) ...
>   dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.6_5.6.15-25.2-645.precise_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>    trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz', which is also in package mysql-client-core-5.5 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
>   dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

I have three identical Dell servers, and did frexh 12.04 installs on all three.  Followed exactly the same install process as on 
http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.6/howtos/ubuntu_howto.html

Two of the servers failed with the error above and the third worked!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to run apt-get -f install on debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70795304/unable-to-run-apt-get-f-install-on-debian)

Answer (score 0):

Installing Mysql 5.5 will resolve the issue as 5.6 has some issues with the Precise default to 5.6. Take a  look at these links for details:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-xtradb-cluster/+bug/1271551

http://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-xtradb-cluster/13060-percona-cluster-5-6-install-problem