# "apt upgrade -y" Not working in kali linux (The following packages have unmet dependencies)

Tags: dependencies, codeblocks, uninstallation

While updating kali machine the following error will shown

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codeblocks-dev : Depends: libcodeblocks0 (= 20.03) but 20.03-3.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and after this i try to fixing issue by typing command **apt --fix-broken install** but!!!

```
└─# apt --fix-broken install                                                                                                                                    100 ⨯
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fastjar jarwrapper kali-wallpapers-2021.4 libaom0 libcbor0 libcodec2-0.9 libfluidsynth2 libfmt7 libgdal29 libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libigdgmm11
  libodbc1 libodbccr2 libqhull8.0 libwireshark14 libwiretap11 libwsutil12 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 python3-orjson ruby-atomic ruby-thread-safe
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  codeblocks-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  codeblocks-dev
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 270 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/522 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,637 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 350701 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../codeblocks-dev_20.03-3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking codeblocks-dev:amd64 (20.03-3.1) over (20.03) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_20.03-3.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/codeblocks/Alignment.h', which is also in package codeblocks-headers 20.03
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_20.03-3.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Nothing happend!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to run apt-get -f install on debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70795304/unable-to-run-apt-get-f-install-on-debian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try using

```
apt dist-upgrade -y
```

> then

```
apt update && apt upgrade -y
```

it might help